# How do I use a variable set in a subclass form a main class inside the subclass?

Tags: android, variables, methods, subclass

I have an `Activity` that has a `PlaceholderFragment` subclass in it. I'm trying to pass an `int` into the `PlaceholderFragment` (which is apparently working, I returned the `int` and printed it to logcat, and it is indeed correct), however when the `onCreateView()` method runs, the `int` that was passed suddenly disappears and resets to 0. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code in my `Activity` that is responsible for passing the `int`:

```
public void setActivityTitle(){
    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    resName = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Name");
    this.ResID = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("ResID");

    PlaceholderFragment pf = new PlaceholderFragment(ResID);
    //↑ I know that PlaceholderFragments should almost always have default constructors, but I was desperate. The default empty constructor is still there though
    pf.receiveResID(ResID);
    //↑ This method is basically a setter for the ResID int
    Log.e("SplitBill","ResID that we got from PlaceholderFragment is " + pf.getResID());
    //↑ This output is as expected, and matches the int that I pass down
    toolbar.setTitle(resName);
}
```

Here are the relevant declaration fields, constructors and getter/setters of the `int` in `PlaceholderFragment`:

```
    private int ResID;

    public PlaceholderFragment() {

    }

    public PlaceholderFragment(int resID) {
        this.ResID = resID;
        Log.e("SplitBill","PlaceholderFragment: Received ResID as " + ResID);
        //↑ This returns the correct int to logcat
    }

    public int getResID() {
        return ResID;
        //Outside the subclass, this returns the correct int. Inside it, this returns 0
    }

    public void receiveResID(int ResID) {
        this.ResID = ResID;
        Log.e("SplitBill","PlaceholderFragment: Received ResID as " + ResID);
        //↑ This also works as expected
    }
```

Here is the section of my `onCreaeView()` that is supposed to use the `int` in a database query:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu, container, false);
        MenuViewModel viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MenuViewModel.class);
        //MenuActivity m = new MenuActivity();
        //int resID = m.getResID();
        //↑ This was my attempt at trying to get the int straight from a getter in the MenuActivity, it returns 0 
        Log.e("SplitBill","From onCreateView(): ResID is " + ResID);
        //↑ This also prints 0 to logcat
        viewModel.setResID(ResID);
```

Edit: `SectionsPagerAdapter` is another subclass inside MenuActivity. It is responsible for getting an instance of `PlaceholderFragment`. Here it is in its entirety:

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should only use empty constructor with Fragments.

```
public static MyFragment newInstance(int someInt) {
    MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("someInt", someInt);
    myFragment.setArguments(args);

    return myFragment;
}
```

`MyFragment fragment = MyFragment.newInstance(5);` is how you should get instance of a fragment and set values.

To get value use `getArguments().getInt("someInt", 0);` inside `onCreate()` method of fragment

Comment: Okay, I've edited that instance. Now I'm getting an error from the `SectionsPagerAdapter`'s `getItem()` method which I have edited the post with, because the `PlaceholderFragment newInstance` code wants more arguments than the `getItem` gives. How do I get around this?

Comment: @SikuM. Please post a new question.